# How to invert the acceleration of a Accelerate Interpolator in Android

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation

I'm using 2 animations on a TextView in my app.

The first one completes, then I change the text of the TextView, then I start the second one. I would like to use an Accelerate Interpolator effect on the **whole** sequence, however if I apply it individually it doesn't work, since the speed will restart on each animation.

I need to invert the animation of the second one, ie. make it start fast and end slow.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use a `DecelerateInterpolator()`:

> An interpolator where the rate of change starts out quickly and and then decelerates.

i.e.

```
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration(300L);
    v.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Missed that one. BTW, probably (another) beginners questions, but whats the "L" on "300L"?

Comment: It indicates that the 300 should be a LONG type. Its like saying 3.0f should be a float instead of a double. If you don't know what that means look up primitive types in Java.

Comment: Is there a way to let them start with the exact speed the other one stopped with? Given I may not have the same distance to pass within the same duration.